# Form wrapped in jQuery causing some issues

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a form wrapped in jQuery.  It slideToggles on click of a div.  This form is self submitting.  So when I display any errors / confirmation on submit of the form, they'll be encapsulated within the jQuery / div.  On the page reload the jQuery hides the form disallowing the user to see the errors / confirmation unless they reopen the contact form.  Now, I clearly am unhappy with that.  What would be a work around this.  I haven't jumped to much into AJAX as of yet.  Would this be my only option here?  And if so, what would be some basic code or a good starting ground to solve this?  Thank you.
Here is the jQuery for when a user clicks the contact div, and below merely represents that it is a self submitting form.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#box').hide();
        $('#contact_link_contact').click(function() {
            $('#box').slideToggle(1500);
            });
        });

<form action="" method="post">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$( form ).submit( function() {
    $.ajax() // send data here
    return false;
});
```

This will prevent the page from reloading when you submit the form, but you will need to send the data using ajax.